# Grid Bootstrap - Error in solve.default(t(x) %*% x) : system computationally singular

Tags: r, time-series, syntax-error, statistics-bootstrap

I'm new of R, thus I apologize in advance if my following question may result a little dumb, but I really need some expert advice.
I have a problem in applying someone else's code to my data. The author's code works perfectly with the examples he provides, and it seems to me I am doing all the correct steps in my case, but apparently I am not.

The main function is:
grid_boot <- function(dat,name,t,ar,grid,bq,c,all,grph)
and I should simply specify the parameter and then running the code given in the script, or at least for the author's example this works.
All the specification in the examples are close to my case, except for the ar parameter.
The ar parameter is the autoregressive order of a time series, so it is simply a number from 1 to n that you choose. My series requires a simple ar = 1, but if I run the code with this specification, R give me back the following error:

> " Error in solve.default(t(x) %*% x) :    system is computationally
> singular: reciprocal condition number = 6.07898e-34 In addition:
> Warning messages: 1: In dat[(ar - k + 2):(n - k + 1)] - dat[(ar - k +
> 1):(n - k)] :   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter
> object length 2: In dat[(ar - k + 2):(n - k + 1)] - dat[(ar - k +
> 1):(n - k)] :   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter
> object length"
> (I know there are other post title with this error, but nothing seems to fit my case)

In the example, the author specifies as follow:

> ```
> orig <- 2    # set to 1 for original data, set to 2 for extended data # 
> t <- 2
> grid <- 200
> bq <- 9999    
> c <- .9
> i <- 7
> d <- np[i,]
> if (orig==1){
> y <- as.matrix(dat[d[1]:(d[2]-18)])
> if (i==4) y <- y[21:82]
> }else{
> y <- as.matrix(dat[d[1]:d[2]])
> }
> name <- "GNP per Capita: 1869-1988"
> ar <- d[3]
> ```

What I can't figure out is the indication ar <- d[3] and in general what precisely he means with specifying i and d. I think this specification is due to the fact that his dataset is made of several variables all written in the same column and they are associated with an index.
When I give these inputs to R (I use RStudio), in the environment pane  appears as ar = 1. When I give the numerical input (ar <- 1) for my exercise instead, the only result is the error above mentioned.

Below, I report my data (as you can see, it is only a single series with few observation, so it should be an easy one) and my inputs, while the script, the example and the data for the example are downloadable [here.](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ebhansen/progs/restat_99.html)
I hope someone can help me figuring out what am I doing wrong and I will be very grateful to anyone who is willing to help a newbie like me.

> ```
> install.packages("pracma")
> library(pracma)
> source(file.choose())
> dat <- as.matrix(read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE))
> print(dat)
>
> USA
> [1,]  0.01075000
> [2,]  0.01116000
> [3,]  0.01214000
> [4,]  0.01309000
> [5,]  0.01668000
> [6,]  0.02991000
> [7,]  0.02776000
> [8,]  0.04218000
> [9,]  0.05415000
> [10,]  0.05895000
> [11,]  0.04256000
> [12,]  0.03306000
> [13,]  0.00622000
> [14,]  0.11035000
> [15,]  0.09132000
> [16,]  0.05737000
> [17,]  0.06486000
> [18,]  0.07647000
> [19,]  0.11266000
> [20,]  0.13509000
> [21,]  0.10316000
> [22,]  0.06161000
> [23,]  0.03212000
> [24,]  0.04317000
> [25,]  0.03561000
> [26,]  0.01859000
> [27,]  0.03741000
> [28,]  0.04009000
> [29,]  0.04827000
> [30,]  0.05398000
> [31,]  0.04235000
> [32,]  0.03029000
> [33,]  0.02952000
> [34,]  0.02607000
> [35,]  0.02805000
> [36,]  0.02931000
> [37,]  0.02338000
> [38,]  0.01552000
> [39,]  0.02188000
> [40,]  0.03377000
> [41,]  0.02826000
> [42,]  0.01586000
> [43,]  0.00002270
> [44,]  0.02677000
> [45,]  0.03393000
> [46,]  0.03226000
> [47,]  0.02853000
> [48,]  0.03839000
> [49,] -0.00000356
> [50,]  0.00001640
> [51,]  0.03157000
> [52,]  0.02069000
> [53,]  0.01465000
> [54,]  0.01622000
> [55,]  0.01622000
>
> dat <- dat
> name <- "Inflation"
> t <- 1
> ar <- 1
> grid <- 200
> bq <- 1999
> c <- .9
> all <- 0
> grph <- 1
>
> out <- grid_boot(dat, name, t, ar, grid, bq, c, all, grph)
> ```

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, because we cannot reproduce the error. We don't know what `grid_boot` is supposed to do or what package it is from, we don't know who the "author" is, and we don't know what the variable `ar` represents.

The error you got is indicative of a non-invertible matrix, which usually arises from colinearity of independent variables in the data. e.g. one field is height in inches, the other is height in cm.

Comment: 'grid_boot'   is the function created in the script by Dr Hansen ("the author") and ar is not a variable, it indicates the series is an autoregressive time series of order n. 
All the necessary information are in the link, because they were too long!